# Plotting first column as X and every other column as a separate line for Y in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, plotting

I have a data file that is formatted as following:

```
1 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
2 0.943177 1.305333 1.735536 1.797774 1.598829 1.737834 1.740041 1.912885 1.566793 2.019060
3 0.939475 1.358506 2.321663 1.853523 1.959409 2.510413 2.150453 2.398809 2.416171 2.565402
4 1.088087 1.123924 2.432605 2.590402 2.093655 3.088580 2.607818 3.159053 2.510439 2.821530
5 1.015587 1.258744 2.416498 2.580757 3.060878 2.942430 3.000413 3.253305 3.690752 3.959206
6 0.944150 1.315485 2.414785 2.574164 3.124374 4.351301 3.059047 3.702346 3.444113 4.392897
7 0.995709 1.645348 2.405321 2.613974 3.081145 4.353721 4.484388 3.194175 3.711591 4.668821
8 1.009326 1.492901 2.358513 2.523792 3.115867 4.392143 4.509854 5.086435 3.266735 4.590688
9 1.042647 1.327413 2.431767 2.577399 3.086926 4.381097 4.438063 5.144038 5.155699 4.230450
10 1.075849 1.291292 2.444103 2.584868 3.073117 4.328016 4.432163 5.145352 5.122751 7.421389
```

Those are 10 rows and 11 columns, with the first column being the values of the X-Axis. I want to draw a separate line for the values of every remaining column. The count of rows and columns can vary, since this is the output of a script.

I want to plot those data using gnuplot.
I tried

> plot "< ./plotscript" matrix using 1:3:2 ever 1::1 with lines palette

but that draws the rows as lines and not the columns.

Comment: If the number of *columns* isn't known in advance, then you may need to do something like this: [Auto plotting all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24563429/4440445)

Comment: Check out this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53899804/5008284) answer which does auto detection and plotting of rows and columns.